# Loop to collect all the image properties from array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

What I am trying to do is "Get the image URLs from all numbers and display them in console" using a loop to collect all the image properties from each number.

What I have so far is:

```
$.get("file.json", function(start){
        for(var numbers in start.data){
            console.log(numbers)
        }
    })
```

It displays the numbers. I don't know what to do next.

This is my JSON data.

```
"id": 2237,
"username": "mark",
"bc": "NBC",
"rap": 987,
"count": 4,
"uniqueCount": 4,
"data": {
    "1533893": {
        "id": 1533893,
        "name": "Bluesteel Egg of Genius",
        "bc": "NBC",
        "type": "hat",
        "originalPrice": 0,
        "image": "https://t3.rbxcdn.com/1e8ba7802f5ab0cdd1fffb936e761aff",
        "rap": 196,
        "stock": 0,
        "userAssetId": {
            "16611316": 0
        }
    },
    "5785985": {
        "id": 5785985,
        "name": "Rusty Tetramino of Competence",
        "bc": "NBC",
        "type": "hat",
        "originalPrice": 0,
        "image": "https://t6.rbxcdn.com/04cd63b742f1b88de64672a79d192e58",
        "rap": 182,
        "stock": 0,
        "userAssetId": {
            "16611313": 0
        }
    },
    "5786026": {
        "id": 5786026,
        "name": "Silver Tetramino of Accomplishment",
        "bc": "NBC",
        "type": "hat",
        "originalPrice": 0,
        "image": "https://t1.rbxcdn.com/c311faa4a2f6ec380d6c86b95171b69a",
        "rap": 252,
        "stock": 0,
        "userAssetId": {
            "16611314": 0
        }
    },
    "5786047": {
        "id": 5786047,
        "name": "Gold Tetramino of Mastery",
        "bc": "NBC",
        "type": "hat",
        "originalPrice": 0,
        "image": "https://t3.rbxcdn.com/54ec21da8b3962aca7c1bd9214cd6f2b",
        "rap": 357,
        "stock": 0,
        "userAssetId": {
            "16611315": 0
        }
    }
},
"success": true
```

}

**Question**

How can I enhance my code to achieve my requirements?

Comment: Gotya. Edited it. thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the object using `Object.keys`

```
 Object.keys(start.data).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, start.data[key].image); 
 });
```

In case that you are unsure if the object has an `image` property then you can add a check to avoid errors:

```
Object.keys(start.data).forEach(function(key) {
  if (start.data[key].image) {
    console.log(key, start.data[key].image);
  }         
});
```

Comment: @chibamuller no problem mate, just in case you want to read more on `Object.keys` then here is the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Yeah after your reply i went to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but i guess all you're trying to do is fetch the links.

So as you can see in the received `JSON` you got a `data` property which contains number objects, each one of them has an `image` property with a url. just fetch this and you're probably good to go.

### EDIT

In order to display all of these images you should run over the "numbers" and create an `<img src=IMAGE_PROPERTY_GOES_HERE/>` per each.

You might wanna use Angular2 *ngFor for that as follows:

```
<img *ngFor="let image of imagesUrl" src=image/>
```

While `imagesUrl` is your Component's property of the collected `image` properties from the JSON.

Hope i made it clear :)

Comment: Yes, i know that. Basicly i want to display all "image" urls from all possible "numbers"

Comment: That's one step ahead. Go back one step :). "in order to display all of these images you should run over the "numbers"" please tell me.

Comment: Edited my answer, in your component you should have a for loop to collect all the `image` property from each `number` in the data. and then you could `ngFor` like i displayed

Comment: "you should have a for loop to collect all the image property from each number"    Yes that's what i'm asking. I fergot how to do that.